# Bash - my script renames a folder incorrectly

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv

I made a script that renames a folder.

```
sudo mv MyFolder MyFolder20130610
```

I run my script and when I see the new folder from console (with **ls**) I see:

`MyFolder20130610??` instead of `MyFolder20130610`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bash script has Windows newlines. Convert to Unix newlines with `dos2unix` or similar utility.

If that doesn't help, open your script in a hex editor and remove the stray bytes at the end of that line.

Comment: cat -v yourscript ;  do you see something strange ?

Comment: @michael, It has a strange character at the end of the line because I was editing the file on windows.

Comment: @Dark Falcon, I used PsPad to convert the file to Unix and It worked.